# Ensure minimal length of last line

Tags: spacing, line-breaking, paragraphs, typography, french

> **This question led to a new feature in a package:**
>   [`impnattypo`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/impnattypo)

One rule in French typography is that the last line of a paragraph should not be shorter than the double of the indentation of the next paragraph.

Is it possible to specify that, or least considering that all paragraphs are indented of the same value, to make sure the last line is longer than twice this value?

A LuaTeX-specific solution is welcome, too.

Comment: The more I read about french typography, the more I think they have some really odd conventions…

Comment: The requirement that the last line of a paragraph should not be shorter than the indent of the next one is also common in german typography.

Comment: @StephanLehmke: then you can also use this option in `impnattypo` in German :-)

Comment: @Raphink I'm very seldomly writing documents with LaTeX, but I've just fixed a bug in the respective configuration option of DocScape to enable this ;-)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You asked for a LuaTeX solution and you get one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luatexbase,luacode}

\begin{luacode}
local PENALTY=node.id("penalty")
last_line_twice_parindent = function (head)
  while head do
    local _w,_h,_d = node.dimensions(head)
    if head.id == PENALTY and head.subtype ~= 15 and (_w < 2 * tex.parindent) then

        -- we are at a glue and have less than 2*\parindent to go
        local p = node.new("penalty")
        p.penalty = 10000
        p.next = head
        head.prev.next = p
        p.prev = head.prev
        head.prev = p
    end

    head = head.next
  end
  return true
end

luatexbase.add_to_callback("pre_linebreak_filter",last_line_twice_parindent,"Raphink")
\end{luacode}


\begin{document}
\parindent = 2cm
\emergencystretch = \hsize

A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart. I am alone, and feel.

The charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the bliss of souls like mine.

I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be
incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now.

\end{document}
```

What it does is it adds ties (`~`) between the words at the end of a paragraph, when the distance to the end is less then 2*`\parindent`. If the `\parindent` is large enough, the paragraphs will get ugly.

[image: ugly paragraph]

---

Note: this does not prevent hyphenation. So the minimal amount is not enforced by an hbox or so. This is an exercise left to the ambitious reader.

Edit: do not hardcode glyph ids...

Comment: Thanks. I've very interesting to see what can be done with LuaTeX. I'll favor the native, more portable solution, but I'm still interested in the LuaTeX one.

Comment: I understand, but I have slight feeling that a native solution based on `parfillskip` will not handle all situations (see my example in my comment to egreg's solution).

Comment: I actually found some other examples in a book of mine where your Lua code worked and not @egreg's setting.

Answer (score 26):

At the end of each paragraph, TeX usually adds infinitely stretchable glue, since the usual setting of `\parfillskip` is equivalent to

```
\setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt plus 1fill}
```

One way might be to set

```
\setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt plus\dimexpr\textwidth-2\parindent}
```

but this would work only for normal paragraphs. In lists one should reset the `\parfillskip` with `\linewidth` instead of `\textwidth`: its value stated as before is *not* dynamically computed, but rather it's fixed. If `\parfillskip` had been a macro, instead of a skip parameter (or if Knuth had provided an `\everyendofpar` token parameter), things would be different. One might redefine `\par`, of course, but LaTeX already does it in some cases.

Note that glue can always stretch *more* than the stated value, but in this case the badness of the line would increase, usually producing an `Underfull \hbox` message. In general I'm inclined not to be overly confident in automatic adjustments like this: *no automated system will be able to do this as well as you*, writes Knuth about page breaking, but paragraph breaking is very much alike, particularly with respect to the final line.

Comment: The `\setlength` solution works well :-)

Comment: @egreg somehow this solution doesn't work with the extreme settings (and the example) from the example I have chosen (see my answer). Perhaps I have made a mistake!?!

Comment: @Patrick: your text works for me. It doesn't if I say `\frenchspacing`; that's why I said that "automated" adjustments are risky. Your tie might not work either, because TeX might choose to hyphenate in the preceding line.

Comment: @egreg can you construct an example where my solution breaks? I'd be very interested!

Comment: @egreg this is an example where your solution doesn't work for me: https://raw.github.com/gist/1215149/a88454e6141968c3fba92b13db9592cbe6f7d7b4/sample.tex - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Patrick: you're right. The length of the last lines is way *less* than twice the parskip. Of course such extreme settings and short paragraphs don't help. Simply: there is no way to keep the stretching below the maximum and TeX overstretches the glue. The last line of the first paragraph has a glue set ratio of 1.18 and a natural width of 65.83347pt: 1.18 means it overstretches, but the overall badness is 166.

Comment: Alright, I'm convinced, too :-) Well, both answers are right in normal conditions, and I'm actually going to use both for my package (the LuaTeX implementation when LuaTeX is used, and @egreg's as default). I'll choose Patrick's implementation as the answer because it's more precise.

Comment: @Raphink Just to be clear: I want to learn and not trying to be a smart ass even if I sometimes sounds like one.

Comment: Just for the record, I'd like to note that the TeX-only possibilities are further discussed in [another question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63762/minimum-length-of-last-line-of-a-paragraph).