# How do I make Chinese character string to have the same length by filling blanks?

Tags: vertical-alignment, chinese, ctex

I am trying to write a document for several people to sign, their names have different numbers of characters. I would like to make them to have the same length by filling blank spaces to them. For example, in the following document

```latex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[UTF8]{article}

\usepackage{ctex}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}

\maketitle

李梅：
\
王晓华：
\
张丽娟：

\end{document}
```

I would like it to produce

```
李 梅：
王晓华：
张丽娟：
```

where the colons should actually be aligned exactly, which is hard to produce.

The most intuitive way to me is writing a random character **in the middle** the first name and make that extra character white. But it seems cumbersome and not easily generalizable. Is there a better way?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy way is to use a `tabular`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{:}}
  First\\
  Second\\
  Third
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

`@{}` suppresses or replaces space between columns, or before the first and after the last column—as used here.

Using your template with Chinese characters, this gives:

```latex
\documentclass[UTF8]{article}
\usepackage{ctex}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{:}}
  李梅\\
  王晓华\\
  张丽娟
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In case you want to add spacing before the colons, you can start the `tabular` for instance with

```latex
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{\kern 2pt:}}
```

[image]

If you want a second column that takes all remaining space until the right margin, you can use the `X` column type of `tabularx` (we tell `tabularx` to make the `X` column large enough so that the table fills the whole `\linewidth`; you can have several `X` columns if you wish, they will share the remaining space left by the other columns):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}l@{:}X@{}}
  First  & \lipsum[1][1-2]\\
  Second & \lipsum[2][1-2]\\
  Third  & \lipsum[3][1-2]
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can start the `tabularx` this way to insert some spacing after the colon:

```latex
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}l@{:\enspace}X@{}}
```

[image]

## Justifying the first column

Following up on a [request in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521264/how-do-i-make-chinese-character-string-to-be-same-length-by-filling-blanks/521285?noredirect=1#comment1318461_521285), here is a little hack to get the first column automatically justified without needing to manually insert spaces between the characters. This definitely requires an Unicode-based engine, such as XeTeX or LuaTeX.

```latex
\documentclass[UTF8]{article}
\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage{collcell}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\@insertHfills}[1]{%
  \unless\ifx#1\@nil
    #1\hfill \expandafter\@insertHfills
  \fi
}

% Append an \hfill after each token of #1 and set \parfillskip to zero
% after the result has been left in the TeX input stream.
\newcommand*{\insertHfills}[1]{%
  \@insertHfills#1\@nil
  \parfillskip=\z@\relax
}
\makeatother

% Define a special column type derived from l (r or c would do as well)
% that wraps the cell contents as the argument of \insertHfills.
\newcolumntype{E}{>{\collectcell\insertHfills}l<{\endcollectcell}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}E@{:}}
  李梅   \\
  王晓华 \\
  王j华  \\
  张丽娟
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Is it possible to have the blank space filled in between the words?

Comment: Which words? What do you mean by filling in a blank space? I don't understand what you are asking here, please be more precise.

Comment: @frougon Most Chinese characters are words in their own right, so I assume this is what zyy means, so the aim is to basically justify these rows. My intuition would be to do [something like this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116569) but for every line, not just the last of the paragraph. I tried to do this but I think LaTeX isn't too happy about "character" spacing of Chinese characters, even if made into their own paragraphs (Usually CJK wants to align into square em boxes).

Comment: @frougon Sorry that I was not clear, so what I was thinking is to add effectively a white space between 李 and 梅，this way, the names would be aligned at both ends. I should have been more clear in the question, sorry about that.

Comment: @svenper I think the package, if combined with `minipage`, might be able to produce the result, let me try on that.

Comment: @svenper and zyy: please have a look at *Justifying the first column* in my updated answer: this implements the request formulated in these comments, if I understood it correctly.

Comment: @svenper I tried the approach I described, it did not work because it is setting the preference for the whole document and I wanted that behavior for only part of the text.