# How to justify the last line in a cell?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, justification

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|}
sdlj lsadfj sdlafjk sdlfj a \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: screnshot1]

The last line is flushed left. I want it to justify.

Similar can be obtained with `\linebreak`:

```
sdlj lsadfj sdlafjk sdlfj a \linebreak\\
```

[image: screenshot2]

But it has an obvious side effect: an excessive line. How to justify it without an excessive line? I found [a trick](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127658/131447) for paragraphs, but it doesn't work for cells.

Comment: I'm not able to experiment so this is just a guess.  Try wrapping the content of the cell in braces, and using the "trick" as the last thing inside the braces.

Comment: If I replace your `\linebreak` with `\parfillskip 0pt`, it works, no braces required.

Comment: This is related to [Is there a tool that makes paragraphs into rectangles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116569/5764) (possible duplicate).

Comment: Tangentially related: [Ensure minimal length of last line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28357/5764)

Comment: if you force justify you will always have to expect excessive space.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes works this way, thanks.

Comment: However, it will fail if **any** line ends up with just a single word, as in `\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|}
succulent cucumbers are delectible\parfillskip 0pt\\
\end{tabular}`.  It goes back to Ulrike's comment, I am sure.

Comment: Try, in the table preamble, `>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{2cm}` (requires the `array` and `ragged2e` packages).