# How to justify the last line of a footnote in microtype style?

Tags: microtype, justification

(I’m using the `microtype` package.)

I wanted to justify the last line of a footnote because it was very close to be full. Here is what it looked like:

[image]

The first two lines are from the same footnote, the third is from the following one.

---

1. I tried `\linebreak`, which justified it the way I wanted but created a blank line in between my two footnotes:

[image]

2. Then, I used `\setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt plus\dimexpr\textwidth-2\parindent}` instead, found in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28358/285989). It does justify the line, and without adding a blank line; but it works as if the `microtype` package wasn’t loaded, i.e. without exdentation, in that case:

[image]

While this is better, it clashes with how justification is done in the rest of the document.

---

**Does anyone know a way to get the same justification as [1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIywx.png) but without the blank line?** (Like in [2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oT44t.png))

MWE (compiled with LuaLaTeX):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum\footnote{Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper [...] non, mi.} dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. % 1) last line not full

Lorem ipsum\footnote{Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper [...] non, mi.\linebreak} dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. % 2) last line full in microtype style but followed by a blank line

Lorem ipsum\footnote{{Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper [...] non, mi.} \setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt plus\dimexpr\textwidth-2\parindent}} dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. % 3) last line full but not in microtype style

Lorem ipsum\footnote{Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper [...] non, mi.} dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. % 4) same as 1), to show there is no blank line after 3)

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would help if you provided and MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}` that we could compile that shows your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance! It’s added!

Comment: This should work in a footnote too: [Manual linebreak with justification but without empty line afterwards](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127644)  (Don't forget the braces around the expression.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton It doesn’t seem to (same result as `\linebreak`). Did you try it with my MWE?

Comment: I've now tried several variations.  The version that comes closest simply puts `\parfillskip0pt Sed...` at the beginning of the footnote (since it's already scoped), but this matches your no.3.  The microtype adjustment doesn't take effect on the last line.  Burying the final period with `\rlap{.}` gets closer, but overshoots by a tiny amount.  I think it's necessary to know how microtype works, but I don't.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you very much for those new ideas anyway! It’s appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two solutions: (1) barbara's suggestion to add `\parfillskip=0pt` would work for normal paragraphs, however footnotes are ended with a strut box, which prevents right protrusion. For cases like this, microtype provides the command `\rightprotrusion`. (2) You could also undo the extra vertical space that `\linebreak` adds. So:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum\footnote{Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, 
   adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula 
   massa, varius a, semper [\ldots] non, mi\parfillskip=0pt \rightprotrusion{.}} 
dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

Lorem ipsum\footnote{Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, 
   adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula 
   massa, varius a, semper [\ldots] non, mi.\linebreak\vspace{-\baselineskip}} 
dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\end{document}
```

Comment: That second option is the best I could hope for! I’m so grateful! Thank you very, very much!