# Snap short or long last lines to perfectly rectangular paragraphs

Tags: horizontal-alignment, paragraphs, typography, parfillskip

**When typesetting paragraphs, I want to ensure their last line is neither overly short *nor* overly long.** To that end, I'm looking for settings that produce either:

- a fully justified, perfectly rectangular paragraph;
- a justified paragraph whose last line is filled more than 20% and less than 80%.

In other words, no paragraph should have a last line that is filled for less than 20% or more than 80%—they should become fully justified instead. The effect could be achieved by manually adding `\parfillskip 0pt` to (only) those paragraphs, but this is exactly what I want to automate instead.

This document shows two good examples and two bad examples:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Page setup
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=3cm]{geometry}

% Typography
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{microtype}
\parindent 0pt
\parskip\baselineskip

\begin{document}

\textbf{I'm looking for settings
        that produce either a)~a~perfect rectangle
        or b)~a paragraph whose last line
        is filled more than 20\% and less than 80\%.}

\section*{Good examples}

\textbf{My perfect paragraph is a~rectangle:}

{
\parfillskip 0pt
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed rhoncus lorem eget ultricies bibendum. Duis luctus felis arcu, sit amet dapibus orci imperdiet id. Duis ullamcorper tortor eget leo fringilla, a lacinia nisl pulvinar. Etiam id facilisis augue. Sed convallis tempus ex, sed accumsan justo pulvinar vitae. Sed id sapien leo. Aliquam posuere ex lacus, ut posuere metus ullamcorper eu. Duis a imperdiet nibh. Donec tincidunt hendrerit nulla, et convallis metus imperdiet nec. Pellentesque massa enim, pharetra in pulvinar a, efficitur nec lorem. Cras mattis ex lorem, et euismod ligula rhoncus. Aenean ultricies quis velit non faucibus.

}

\textbf{However, this is not always achievable (and that's fine):}

{
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed rhoncus lorem eget ultricies bibendum. Duis luctus felis arcu, sit amet dapibus orci imperdiet id. Duis ullamcorper tortor eget leo fringilla, a lacinia nisl pulvinar. Etiam id facilisis augue. Sed convallis tempus ex, sed accumsan justo pulvinar vitae. Sed id sapien leo. Aliquam posuere ex lacus, ut posuere metus ullamcorper eu. Duis a imperdiet nibh. Donec tincidunt hendrerit nulla, et convallis metus imperdiet nec. Pellentesque massa enim, pharetra in pulvinar a, efficitur nec lorem. Cras mattis ex lorem, et euismod ligula rhoncus.

}

\section*{Bad examples}

\textbf{This last line is too short:}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed rhoncus lorem eget ultricies bibendum. Duis luctus felis arcu, sit amet dapibus orci imperdiet id. Duis ullamcorper tortor eget leo fringilla, a lacinia nisl pulvinar. Etiam id facilisis augue. Sed convallis tempus ex, sed accumsan justo pulvinar vitae. Sed id sapien leo. Aliquam posuere ex lacus, ut posuere metus ullamcorper eu. Duis a imperdiet nibh. Donec tincidunt hendrerit nulla, et convallis metus imperdiet nec. Pellentesque massa enim, pharetra in pulvinar a, efficitur nec lorem.

\textbf{The above can be fixed with}
\verb!\parfillskip 0pt plus 0.80\textwidth!
\textbf{but that doesn't help for the case below.}

\textbf{This last line should have been justified (note the small gap at the end):}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed rhoncus lorem eget ultricies bibendum. Duis luctus felis arcu, sit amet dapibus orci imperdiet id. Duis ullamcorper tortor eget leo fringilla, a lacinia nisl pulvinar. Etiam id facilisis augue. Sed convallis tempus ex, sed accumsan justo pulvinar vitae. Sed id sapien leo. Aliquam posuere ex lacus, ut posuere metus ullamcorper eu. Duis a imperdiet nibh. Donec tincidunt hendrerit nulla, et convallis metus imperdiet nec. Pellentesque massa enim, pharetra in pulvinar a, efficitur nec lorem. Cras mattis ex lorem, et euismod ligula rhoncus. Aenean ultricies quis velit non ut faucibus.

\textbf{The above can be fixed with}
\verb!\parfillskip 0pt!
\textbf{but that doesn't help for the case below.}

\end{document}
```

A solution should consist of **adjustments in the preamble only**. No special commands should be required at the beginning or end of any paragraph. I hope that, as in several related cases, it can be solved with a special bit of glue in `\parfillskip`, but I'm not sure whether this is possible.

---

**Related questions**, whose solutions I have tried but do not produce the intended output:

- [Avoid just nearly filled last lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41412/avoid-just-nearly-filled-last-lines) solves *long* last lines, but not *short* ones.
- [Minimum length of last line of a paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63762/minimum-length-of-last-line-of-a-paragraph) solves *short* last lines, but not *long* ones.
- [Is there a tool that makes paragraphs into rectangles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116569/is-there-a-tool-that-makes-paragraphs-into-rectangles) too strongly prefers rectangles, even if the last line is only filled half, with excessive interword spacing as a result.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'd prefer a (La)TeX solution if there is one.

Comment: Not sure how to automate but, in an `\mbox`, place the last several words of the paragraph and a `\hspace{.2\linewidth}`, so that your 1st paragraph (in `article` class) would be `When typesetting paragraphs, I want to ensure their last line is neither overly short nor overly long. To that end, I'm looking for settings \mbox{that produce either:\hspace{.2\linewidth}}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle A natural width of 20–80% is fine, so a line with a natural width of 21% is fine as well.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes It's the automation that is difficult. Manually adding `\parfilskip0pt` to selected paragraphs would also work, but I want TeX to apply this automatically to paragraphs with small or long last liens.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Strictly speaking, a 19% line should stretch to full width, yes. (In an ideal situation, there would be an exception for one-line paragraphs.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No, the paragraph should always be justified. Left-justified when the last line is 20–80% long; fully justified in all other cases.

Comment: even if it is a 10 line paragraph which ends with two words, the most likely posssible way to meet your constraints woul dbe to stretch those two words and put almost an entire line of white space in between. In some cases it may be possble to use one less lien and force the words to the previous line, but not in general

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't think the 10-line + 2-word scenario is likely; an alternative solution is 10-line + 5-word (assuming that 5 words are longer than 20%).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I clarified the "left-justified" language in the question.

Comment: if that is what you want you need to give more testable constraints, almost any automatoc way I can see to meet the requested constraints wouldn't bring more words down into the last line, it would just stretch out the existing text.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The solutions I've seen for "no short last line" do not result in such excessive stretching on the last line, so I assume (but I'm not sure) that that would not happen in this case either.

Comment: @RubenVerborgh typically they do, unless the paragraphs are quite long, to give more flexibility to avoid the short lines, with paragraphs of say 1-3 lines avoiding excessive word space is likely not possible.

Comment: The [impnattypo](https://ctan.org/pkg/impnattypo) package could be helpful for similar issues? - It was recommended at the similar question [Ensure minimal length of last line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28357/9075).

Answer (score 4):

This approach is *semi*-automatic, in that one must still enclose the paragraph in a `\fixit` macro.

**REVISED APPROACH**

Rather than dissect the paragraph word by word, as in the ORIGINAL APPROACH below, here, I just measure the length of the `\hbox` containing the paragraph material, and decide, based on the length, whether to employ a trailing `\hspace{}\mbox` and/or a `\parfillskip0pt`.

The macro provides an optional argument if tweaking is required.  It represents the largest fractional line overrun that will be compressed away, currently set to `.05` (5%).  You will know it needs tweaking if a line that you thought would be compressed away gets expanded into a whole new widely spaced line.  Setting the default value to `.0` will eliminate any problems, but at the expense that some lines that could otherwise be compressed to eliminate trailing widows are instead expanded so that the widow takes up 20% of the subsequent line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in,top=0cm,bottom=0cm]{geometry}
\newcommand\fixit[2][.05]{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\hspace{\parindent}#2}\fixithelp{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand\fixithelp[2]{%
  \wd0=\dimexpr\wd0-\linewidth\relax%
  \ifdim\wd0>0pt\relax%
    \fixithelp{#1}{#2}%
  \else%
    \wd0=\dimexpr\wd0+\linewidth\relax
    \ifdim\wd0>.9\linewidth\relax%
      {\parfillskip0pt\relax#2\par}%
    \else%
      \ifdim\wd0>.8\linewidth\relax%
        {\parfillskip0pt\relax#2\hspace{.2\linewidth}\par}%
      \else%
        \ifdim\wd0<#1\linewidth\relax%
          {\parfillskip0pt\relax#2\par}%
        \else%
          \ifdim\wd0<.2\linewidth\relax%
            {\parfillskip0pt\relax#2\hspace{.8\linewidth}\mbox{}\par}%
          \else%
            #2%
          \fi
        \fi
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi%
}
\sloppy
\parskip1ex
\begin{document}
\noindent\rule{.2\linewidth}{2pt}\hfill\rule{.2\linewidth}{2pt}

\fixit{%
yakity yack, paragraphs, I want to \textit{ensure their last line} is neither 
overly short nor overly long. To that end, I'm looking for settings that 
produce either:}

\fixit{%
yack, yakity yack, paragraphs, I want to \textit{ensure their last line} is neither 
overly short nor overly long. To that end, I'm looking for settings that 
produce either:}

\fixit{%
yakity yack, yakity yack, paragraphs, I want to \textit{ensure their last line} is neither 
overly short nor overly long. To that end, I'm looking for settings that 
produce either:}

\fixit{%
yack, yakity yack, yakity yack, paragraphs, I want to \textit{ensure their last line} is neither 
overly short nor overly long. To that end, I'm looking for settings that 
produce either:}

\fixit{%
yackity yack, yakity yack, yakity yack, paragraphs, I want to \textit{ensure their last line} is neither 
overly short nor overly long. To that end, I'm looking for settings that 
produce either:}

\fixit{%
yack, yackity yack, yakity yack, yakity yack, paragraphs, I want to \textit{ensure their last line} is neither 
overly short nor overly long. To that end, I'm looking for settings that 
produce either:}

\fixit{%
yackity yack, yackity yack, yakity yack, yakity yack, paragraphs, I want to \textit{ensure their last line} is neither 
overly short nor overly long. To that end, I'm looking for settings that 
produce either:}

\fixit{%
yack, yackity yack, yackity yack, yakity yack, yakity yack, paragraphs, I want to \textit{ensure their last line} is neither 
overly short nor overly long. To that end, I'm looking for settings that 
produce either:}

\fixit{%
yackity yack, yackity yack, yackity yack, yakity yack, yakity yack, paragraphs, I want to \textit{ensure their last line} is neither 
overly short nor overly long. To that end, I'm looking for settings that 
produce either:}

\fixit{%
yack, yackity yack, yackity yack, yackity yack, yakity yack, yakity yack, paragraphs, I want to \textit{ensure their last line} is neither 
overly short nor overly long. To that end, I'm looking for settings that 
produce either:}

\fixit{%
yackity yack, yackity yack, yackity yack, yackity yack, yakity yack, yakity yack, paragraphs, I want to \textit{ensure their last line} is neither 
overly short nor overly long. To that end, I'm looking for settings that 
produce either:}

\fixit{%
yack, yackity yack, yackity yack, yackity yack, yackity yack, yakity yack, yakity yack, paragraphs, I want to \textit{ensure their last line} is neither 
overly short nor overly long. To that end, I'm looking for settings that 
produce either:}

\fixit{%
yackity yack, yackity yack, yackity yack, yackity yack, yackity yack, yakity yack, yakity yack, paragraphs, I want to \textit{ensure their last line} is neither 
overly short nor overly long. To that end, I'm looking for settings that 
produce either:}

\fixit{%
yack, yackity yack, yackity yack, yackity yack, yackity yack, yackity yack, yakity yack, yakity yack, paragraphs, I want to \textit{ensure their last line} is neither 
overly short nor overly long. To that end, I'm looking for settings that 
produce either:}

\fixit{%
yackity yack, yackity yack, yackity yack, yackity yack, yackity yack, yackity yack, yakity yack, yakity yack, paragraphs, I want to \textit{ensure their last line} is neither 
overly short nor overly long. To that end, I'm looking for settings that 
produce either:}

\fixit{%
yack, yackity yack, yackity yack, yackity yack, yackity yack, yackity yack, yackity yack, yakity yack, yakity yack, paragraphs, I want to \textit{ensure their last line} is neither 
overly short nor overly long. To that end, I'm looking for settings that 
produce either:}

\fixit{%
yackity yack, yackity yack, yackity yack, yackity yack, yackity yack, yackity yack, yackity yack, yakity yack, yakity yack, paragraphs, I want to \textit{ensure their last line} is neither 
overly short nor overly long. To that end, I'm looking for settings that 
produce either:}

\end{document}
```

Margins=1.5in

[image]

Margins = 1.7in

[image]

Margins = 1.9in

[image]

**ORIGINAL APPROACH**

But what the macro does is regurgitate the paragraph word by word until it is down to the last 4 words.  Then, it determines how many of those last words are required to exceed `.2\linewidth` and bundles them together inside an `\mbox` along with a `\hspace{.2\linewidth}`.  If the last 3 words do not exceed `.2\linewidth`, then it uses all 4 in the `\mbox`.

For what the OP requests, `\sloppy` will almost assuredly be required, since we are talking about changing the text length by `.4\linewidth` in one fell swoop (which is almost always an undesired thing).  So I added it.

One thing that will break the approach is if a previously opened group is ended within the last 4 words of the paragraph.  That would apply, for example, when closing a long `\textit` near the end of a paragraph.

The other thing to note is that a perfectly rectangular paragraph will *never* be created with this approach, because of the added `\hspace` at the end of the paragraph.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\fixit[1]{\fixithelp#1 \cr\relax}
\def\fixithelp#1 #2 #3 #4 #5\relax{\ifx \cr#5\finishup#1 #2 #3 #4\relax%
  \else#1 \fixithelp#2 #3 #4 #5\relax\fi}
\def\finishup#1 #2 #3 #4\relax{ %
  \setbox0=\hbox{#4}%
  \ifdim\wd0>.2\linewidth\relax #1 #2 #3 \mbox{#4\hspace{.2\linewidth}}\else%
    \setbox0=\hbox{#3 #4}%
    \ifdim\wd0>.2\linewidth\relax #1 #2 \mbox{#3 #4\hspace{.2\linewidth}}\else%
      \setbox0=\hbox{#2 #3 #4}%
      \ifdim\wd0>.2\linewidth\relax #1 \mbox{#2 #3 #4\hspace{.2\linewidth}}\else%
        \mbox{#1 #2 #3 #4\hspace{.2\linewidth}}%
      \fi%
    \fi%
  \fi%
}
\sloppy
\parskip1em
\begin{document}
\fixit{typesetting 
paragraphs, I want to \textit{ensure their last line} is neither 
overly short nor overly long. To that end, I'm looking for settings that 
produce either:}

\fixit{%
paragraphs, I want to \textit{ensure their last line} is neither 
overly short nor overly long. To that end, I'm looking for settings that 
produce either:}

\fixit{%
paragraphs, I want to \textit{ensure their last line} is neither 
overly short nor overly long. To that end, I'm looking for settings that 
produce overlylongwords:}

\fixit{%
I want to \textit{ensure their last line} is neither 
overly short nor overly long. To that end, I'm looking for settings that 
produce overlylongwords:}

\fixit{%
typesetting paragraphs, I want to \textit{ensure their last line} is neither 
overly short nor overly long. To that end, I'm looking for settings that 
produce I I I I:}

\fixit{%
typesetting I want to \textit{ensure their last line} is neither 
overly short nor overly long. To that end, I'm looking for settings that 
produce I I I I:}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, definitely a good start! If there's somehow a way to do this without the `\fixit`, then this seems like a good approach. Out of curiosity, could you elaborate on why a solution is not possible / difficult with only glue settings (as the related problems linked to in the question do)?

Comment: @RubenVerborgh Thanks.  Unfortunately, glue is not my specialty, and so I only knew how to attack the problem with a sledgehammer, and not a scalpel.