# Make \section unaffected by \parfillskip

Tags: sectioning, paragraphs, typography, sections-paragraphs, parfillskip

**To avoid widow words at the last line of a paragraph, I adjust `parfillskip`:**

```
\parfillskip 0pt plus 0.75\textwidth
```

While this gives nicer paragraphs, it also stretches section titles a little, as you can see below.
The first title is with the default `parfillskip`, the second with `0pt plus 0.75\textwidth`:

[image]

**How can I keep my `parfillskip` setting for paragraphs, but not for titles?**

This code showcases the effect for text and titles ([preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQt99.png)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section{This is a section title}
\lipsum[1]
\section{This is a section title}

% Fill the last line of paragraphs for minimum 25%
\parfillskip 0pt plus 0.75\textwidth
\section{This is a section title}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: My impression is that you create more paragraphing problems than you solve, with that setting of `\parfillskip`.

Comment: @egreg I'm quite happy with what it does to the paragraphs actually; just not do the titles: http://i.imgur.com/YAVeaTu.png But other suggestions to achieve the same effect with paragraphs are welcome.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The section title is typeset by `\@sect`, which happily encloses the relevant part in a group. At the end it adds `\@@par`, which is the primitive `\par`.

Thus we can safely patch `\@sect` (for numbered sections) and `\@ssect` (for unnumbered sections):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@sect}{\begingroup}{\begingroup\parfillskip=0pt plus 1fil\relax}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@ssect}{\begingroup}{\begingroup\parfillskip=0pt plus 1fil\relax}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section{This is a section title}
\lipsum[1]

% Fill the last line of paragraphs for minimum 25%
\parfillskip 0pt plus 0.75\textwidth
\section{This is a section title}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Note that this solution also works for `\subsection` (despite what `\@sect` might make you think).

Comment: how can I apply this for `section*`?

Comment: @EmitTaste Apply the same patch to `\@ssect`. I added the code, thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 1):

For the `memoir` class, it suffices to add to the preamble:

```
\setsecheadstyle{\Large\parfillskip=0pt plus 1fil}
```

Comment: And for KOMA-Script classes you do not need to do anything, because they already support `\parfillskip` > 0.

Answer (score 0):

Since section titles should not be formatted with flush-right margins in any case -- despite the default document classes doing exactly that -- you should declare `\raggedright` in the definition of the sectioning; and once you do that, the `\parfillskip` is irrelevant.

Define the sectioning however you want:

- with memoir or koma or other nice document class;
- using a package like titlesec or some such;
- with sectioning of the standard document classes using `\@startsection`
- or, the most hackish, patch commands like `\@sect`

For example, the basic "article" class uses

```
\newcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                               {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                               {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                               {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
```

so a document setup could include a `\renewcommand` of that with `\raggedright` inserted in the font-style argument

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                               {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                               {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                               {\normalfont\raggedright\Large\bfseries}}
```