# Change \rigthhyphenmin at end of paragraph only

Tags: paragraphs, hyphenation

Into paragraph I use:

```
\lefthyphenmin=2  
\righthyphenmin=2
```

and it's correctly for me. But some paragraphs ends with too short right part (two ot three letters) of hypenated word (looks like widow-letters in words context).
In this case I'm using one of the folowing methods (or both):

1) `\mbox{last word of paragraph}`, or
2) set `\parfillskip=` after paragraph.
(I wrote `\ParFilling{}{}{}{}{}` macros with actions:

```
\parfillskip=1.5\parindent plus .9\textwidth \par
\parfillskip=0pt plus .9\textwidth \par
\parfillskip=0pt \par
\looseness=-1
\looseness=+1
```

choiced by `1`. So `\ParFilling{}{}{}{}{1}` add `\parfillskip=0pt \par` to paragraph, and so one. This macros inserted by script at end of the each paragraph, and I can change appearance of paragraph with turning on or off according field).

But may be we can change hyphenation rules (e.g.`\righthyphenmin=6`, as I set for TOC) only at last word (or words) of paragraph? Or select last word(s) via script and put it in `\nohyphens{last (long) word of paragraph}` for **hyphenat** package?
Some ideas? Thank you.

Comment: I don't think there is any reasonable way to do this in classic tex or xetex (you could probably use a callback filter to adjust the last word of a paragraph in luatex)

Comment: If the final word is quite long, would you tolerate a hyphenation that places, say, four or more letters on the final line? Or are you looking to disable hyphenation outright for any final word in a paragraph?

Comment: There are many long words in my language (russian), and I think about first case - disable a hypenation, only for word, shortest, say, 8 or 10 letters. Word, that longer this, can be hyphenated. So length right-hypenated part must >= 1.5\parindent.

Comment: Perhaps, solution located in paragraph-space area, like in that post:[minimal-length-of-last-line](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28357/ensure-minimal-length-of-last-line/28358#28358), and that: [minimum-length-of-last-line-of-a-paragraph](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63762/minimum-length-of-last-line-of-a-paragraph). There is special solution for [russian-style paragraph](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb28-2/tb89glister.pdf)