# Minimum number of characters in the last line of a paragraph

Tags: line-breaking, paragraphs

Last line of paragraph should end with a minimum of five characters of the word. Is it possible to obtain this with LaTeX ?

Comment: A simple, but non-automatic, way of achieving this objective is to put a "tie", `~`, between the final two words of a paragraph if the very last word contains four or fewer characters.

Comment: Related: [Ensure minimal length of last line](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28357/5764)